# NodeJS How do I change node request url

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to change API 'keyword' parameter so it displays different results each times but not sure how to do this (http://localhost:3009/api/get-products/?keywords=naruto) .

```
    app.get("/api/get-products/:keywords",async (req, res) => {
  client.execute('aliexpress.affiliate.product.query', {
    'app_signature':'maarifahmall',
    // 'category_ids':'111,222,333',
    'fields':'commission_rate,sale_price',
    'keywords':req.params.keywords,
    'max_sale_price':'100',
    'min_sale_price':'15',
    'page_no':'1',
    'page_size':'50',
    'platform_product_type':'ALL',
    'sort':'SALE_PRICE_ASC',
    'target_currency':'USD',
    'target_language':'EN',
    'tracking_id':'maarifahmall',
    'ship_to_country':'US',
    'delivery_days':'3'
  }, 
  function(error, response) {
    if (!error) {
      res.send(response['resp_result']);
      // ['result']['products']['product']
    } else {
      res.send(error);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: [@Shaiful](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12297653/shaiful-rizal-shaharudin) I think your are looking for query parameters in express

Comment: This means that whenever you shuffle your get request with different keywords, you might get different results.

Comment: yes exactly, but how ?

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.getProducts = (req, res, next) => {
  const page = +req.query.page || 1;
  let totalItems;

  Product.find()
    .countDocuments()
    .then((numProducts) => {
      totalItems = numProducts;
      return Product.find()
        .skip((page - 1) * ITEMS_PER_PAGE)
        .limit(ITEMS_PER_PAGE);
    })
    .then((products) => {
      res.render("home/productshop", {
        prods: products,
        pageTitle: "Shop Product",
        path: "/products",
        isAuthenticated: req.session.isLoggedIn,
        csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),

        currentPage: page,
        hasNextPage: ITEMS_PER_PAGE * page < totalItems,
        hasPreviousPage: page > 1,
        nextPage: page + 1,
        previousPage: page - 1,
        lastPage: Math.ceil(totalItems / ITEMS_PER_PAGE),
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

See here, on page const simply I stored my query numbers and I use this where I want to use it.

### In your case simply you can set as if "naruto" is a keyword then execute below code else other response and if keywords are more than 2 to 3 you can go with looping.